# How to use UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory in Dropwizard v1.1.0

Tags: dropwizard

I need to call DAO methods outside resource in dropwizard. 
Looking at the manual Im unclear how to use it. The manual says

```
SessionDao dao = new SessionDao(hibernateBundle.getSessionFactory());
ExampleAuthenticator exampleAuthenticator = new
    UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory(hibernateBundle)
           .create(ExampleAuthenticator.class, SessionDao.class, dao);
```

Can anyone show me the usage of `exampleAuthenticator` methods which call DAO.

Thanks, Kedar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution

```
/** initializing proxy dao for authorization */
AuthenticatorDAOProxy authenticatorDAOProxy = new UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory(hibernateBundle)
            .create(AuthenticatorDAOProxy.class, DeviceDAO.class, deviceDAO);
```

We can now use `authenticatorDAOProxy` outside jersey resources

One thing to note., `AuthenticatorDAOProxy` should have a constructor accepting `DeviceDAO`

Now your proxyDao will look like

```
public class AuthenticatorDAOProxy {

  private DeviceDAO deviceDAO;

  public AuthenticatorDAOProxy(DeviceDAO deviceDAO) {
    this.deviceDAO = deviceDAO;
  }

  @UnitOfWork
  public Boolean checkIsDeviceValid(String deviceId, User user) {
    Device device = deviceDAO.getByDeviceIdAndUser(deviceId, user);
    if (device != null && device.getIsActive() == true) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe you don't need `AuthenticatorDAOProxy` to have a constructor accepting `DeviceDAO`.  There are a couple of overloads of the `create` method in `UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory`; and one of them would let you just write `... .create(AuthenticatorDAOProxy.class)` if a no-arg constructor were available

Answer (score 0):

Each Dropwizard module have a testsuite. Here is the answer you are looking for: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/release/1.1.x/dropwizard-hibernate/src/test/java/io/dropwizard/hibernate/UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactoryTest.java#L121-L151

The logic is:

1. The `DAO` object instance holds a reference to the Hibernate SessionFactory;
2. A method that access the DB calls `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`. The sample code is executing a native query and returns true if at least one result row is returned from the DB;
3. The `OAuthAuthenticator` instance holds a reference to the `DAO` instance and calls the appropriate method of the `DAO`.

The test case is here: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/release/1.1.x/dropwizard-hibernate/src/test/java/io/dropwizard/hibernate/UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactoryTest.java#L64-L74