# JPQL Query not getting executed because of session

Tags: java, hibernate, dao, dropwizard

I am trying to run an application in which I am using JPQL. In the beginning of the application, I am running,

```
public class CacheManager {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CacheManager.class);
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Student> temp;

    public static void initLoadingCache(StudentDAO dao) {
        LOGGER.debug("Fetching...");
        List<Student> students = dao.findAll();
    }
```

where the `findall()` is as follows alongwith its query:

```
public List<Student> findAll() {
        return namedQuery("Student.findAll").getResultList();
    }
```

where the query is like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "Student.findAll",
                query = "SELECT p FROM Student p")
        )})
```

I keep getting `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution context` but I am not sure why I get this for this particular query even though I am not doing multithreading or any Async calls. Any fix would help a lot.
Entire stacktrace:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution context
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ManagedSessionContext.currentSession(ManagedSessionContext.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:464)
    at io.dropwizard.hibernate.AbstractDAO.currentSession(AbstractDAO.java:44)
    at io.dropwizard.hibernate.AbstractDAO.namedQuery(AbstractDAO.java:76)
    at com.xyz.abc.student.db.StudentDAO.findAll(StudentDAO.java:26)
    at com.xyz.abc.student.db.CacheManager.initLoadingCache(CacheManager.java:24)
    at com.xyz.abc.student.StudentService.run(StudentService.java:118)
    at com.xyz.abc.student.StudentService.run(StudentService.java:43)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:43)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:87)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
    at com.xyz.abc.student.StudentService.main(StudentService.java:46)
```

I further tried this which works

```
public StudentDAO(SessionFactory factory, int queryTimeout) {
        super(factory);
        sessionFactory = factory;
        this.queryTimeout = queryTimeout;
    }

public List<Student> findAll() throws Exception{
        List<Student> students = null;
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
            ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            try {
                students = list((Query<Student>) namedQuery("Student.findAll"));
                transaction.commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                transaction.rollback();
                throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
            ManagedSessionContext.unbind(sessionFactory);
        }
        return students;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: Edit your question with the entire stacktrace, you might be calling `initLoadingCache` from the wrong place

Comment: @Guillaume there you go!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@UnitOfWork` on your `findAll` method.

See the [documentation](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/stable/manual/hibernate.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

To use the DAO classes in Dropwizard, you can just use the `@UnitOfWork` annotation in Jersey resources, but elsewhere you need to additionally instantiate your class with `UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory`. It will create a proxy of your class, which will open a Hibernate session with a transaction around methods with the `@UnitOfWork` annotation. [(Dropwizard documentation)](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/hibernate.html#transactional-resource-methods-outside-jersey-resources)

One example is here: [How to use UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory in Dropwizard v1.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000861/how-to-use-unitofworkawareproxyfactory-in-dropwizard-v1-1-0)

Comment: Can you provide the example based on the code I posted?

Comment: further, I am manually opening the sessions so it shouldn't be a problem.